# How to aggregate rows that contain NA values in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I would like to go from this:

```
City   State    x1  x2  x3
 
NA        CA    10  10  10

SD        CA    10  10  10 

NA        CA    10  10  10

SF        CA    10  10  10

FW        TX    5   5   5   

NA        TX    5   5   5

NA        TX    5   5   5
```

To This:

```
State   sum 

CA      120

TX      45
```

```
col1 <- c(NA,'SD',NA,'SF','FW', NA, NA)
col2 <- c('CA', 'CA', 'CA', 'CA', 'TX', 'TX', 'TX')
col3 <- c(10,10,10,10,5,5,5)
col4 <- c(10,10,10,10,5,5,5)
col5 <- c(10,10,10,10,5,5,5)

df <- data.frame(City=col1, State=col2, x1=col3, x2=col4,x3=col5)
col6 <- c('CA', 'TX')
col7 <- c(120, 45)

solution <- data.frame(State=col6, sum=col7)
```

edit: fixed error in data frame. and change 'NA' to NA. Thank you to Ronak for replying so quickly.

Comment: Your question title is not clear? What does NA mean here?

Comment: Plz correct `df`: `Error in data.frame(City = col1, State = col2, x1 = col3, x2 = col4, x3 = col5) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 7, 6, 8`

Comment: @AnilGoyal I apologize, I made NA into a string.

Comment: No, you misunderstood me.  What's the relevance of NA in calculation here.  The output seems irrelevant of NA

Comment: You can just ignore the City variable, regardless of it having NAs or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subset the columns to sum from `cur_data()` in `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(State) %>%
  summarise(sum = sum(select(cur_data(), x1:x3), na.rm = TRUE))

#  State   sum
#  <chr> <int>
#1 CA      120
#2 TX       45
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(City = c(NA, "SD", NA, "SF", "FW", NA, NA), State = c("CA", 
"CA", "CA", "CA", "TX", "TX", "TX"), x1 = c(10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
5L, 5L, 5L), x2 = c(10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 5L, 5L, 5L), x3 = c(10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 5L, 5L, 5L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Comment: WOW. Thank you Ronak for replying so quickly.

Comment: Is there a reason why you use `cur_data()` over `across()`? I'm only asking because it seems more intuitive to use `sum(across(x1:x3), na.rm = TRUE)`.

Comment: `across` is still a loop which I don't think we need just to select the columns, `select` does a better job of it.

Answer (score 3):

@Ronak Shah solution is way better, but here is another longer but still effective solution to get to know some useful functions for future's sake:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(State) %>%
  summarise(across(x1:x3, ~ sum(.x, na.rm = TRUE))) %>%   # We use across() for column-wise operations
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(sum = sum(c_across(x1:x3), na.rm = TRUE)) %>%    # We use rowwise() function + c_across() for row wise operations
  select(-c(x1:x3))

# A tibble: 2 x 2
# Rowwise: 
  State   sum
  <chr> <int>
1 CA      120
2 TX       45
```

This is also very useful and closer to the one mentioned above:

```
df %>%
  group_by(State) %>%
  summarise(sum = sum(c_across(x1:x3), na.rm = TRUE))

# A tibble: 2 x 2
  State   sum
  <chr> <int>
1 CA      120
2 TX       45
```

Comment: Alternatively: `df %>% 
  group_by(State) %>% 
  summarise(sum = sum(c_across(starts_with('x'))))`

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann , Yes, that's also very good. I've never used `c_across()` in a column wise operation before but here it does the trick.

Comment: I am unable to understand what's the relevance of NA in this question????

Comment: the question says `How to aggregate rows that contain NA values in R`

Comment: @AnilGoyal I didn't get that too but I took a look at the desired output and thought that will deliver the result.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `data.table` methods for efficiency.  Convert the data.frame to 'data.table (`setDT(df)`), grouped by 'State, specify the columns as a `pattern` of column names in `.SDcols`, get the `rowSums` of the Subset of Data.table (`.SD`) and `sum` it

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[ , sum(rowSums(.SD), na.rm = TRUE), State, 
     .SDcols = patterns('^x\\d+$')]
#   State  V1
#1:    CA 120
#2:    TX  45
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(City = c(NA, "SD", NA, "SF", "FW", NA, NA), State = c("CA", 
"CA", "CA", "CA", "TX", "TX", "TX"), x1 = c(10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
5L, 5L, 5L), x2 = c(10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 5L, 5L, 5L), x3 = c(10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 5L, 5L, 5L)), class = "data.frame",
   row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```